# View the variable values in the math behind MySQL FULLTEXT search

Tags: php, python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting unexpectedly inconsistent `score` values on my `FULLTEXT` searches in MySQL.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT id, MATCH(description) AGAINST ('$query' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM product ORDER BY score DESC
```

To clarify: I have a Python script that first populates my database then runs other MySQL queries (such as `MATCH() AGAINST` above), all by executing `.php` web pages that contain the MySQL (i.e. `insert.php`, `delete.php`, `search.php`). (My professor's idea.) The MySQL query above gives the same `score` value each time I run it through the MySQL Shell or PHPMyAdmin, but changes when the query is run through the Python script.

Therefore, I'd like to be able to see the variables going into the `MATCH() AGAINST` operation (see "How Relevancy is Calculated" here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) to see what variables my Python script is causing to change, in hopes of pinpointing why my `score` value changes each time I run the script

---

**Step 1 - Python script deletes database contents by calling `delete.php` on each table in the database**:

`x.x.x.x/delete.php?table=product&conditions=id>='0'`

`x.x.x.x/delete.php?table=customer&conditions=id>='0'`

etc...

**Step 2 - Python script inserts `product` table entries by calling `insert.php` and inserting a `name` and `description`**:

`x.x.x.x/insert.php?table=product&columns=name,description&values='V5','This bottle of shampoo is heftier than the other brands.'`

etc...

**Step 3 - Python script runs a `FULLTEXT` search on the `description` column of the `products` table by using `MATCH() AGAINST` by calling `search.php`**:

`x.x.x.x/search.php&query=bottle`

(`search.php` then runs the MySQL query seen at the top of this post)

Comment: Python or PHP as tagged? `SELECT '$query' as debug, ...`?

Comment: There's a mix of Python, PHP, and MySQL code going on here, and I don't know which code is causing the `score` value to change

Comment: What is the PHP part? Only PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: My Python script calls PHP web pages. Each PHP web page executes a different MySQL query. I suppose it should simply be tagged as MySQL if all I'm asking for is how to get detailed variable information on the MySQL `MATCH() AGAINST` command

Comment: That's also relevant. You should edit your question and describe how you interact between Python and PHP providing code snippets of both, Python and PHP.

Comment: My particular situation is quite peculiar and hard to concisely convey. If there's some way to view the values of the variables used in `FULLTEXT` searches as discussed on this page ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html ) like `TF` and `IDF`, I think I'll be able to troubleshoot more effectively

Comment: This might happen due to the way MySQL updates the fulltext index after changes. Try to run `optimize table tablename` after all changes are done (so between step 2 and 3) to refresh the index and to ensure everything is committed and up to date.

Comment: Have you checked what information `EXPLAIN` is giving you?

Comment: @Solarflare - Oh hey, it works! Thanks so much. Why do I have to optimize the table every time I want to do a FULLTEXT search on the `description` column after deleting/adding table entries? Is it just a peculiarity caused by using a Python script to delete and add the entries?

Comment: No, in normal operation, you usually don't need to run an optimize for every change (and it has nothing to do with python, you get the same effect if you do it in the client). But neither changing 200% of the rows nor caring about the exact score are "normal operation", and if you want an exact, reproducible situation you should include it (it only costs some time), for a production environment you would definitely remove it (and do it in e.g. in a weekly maintenance job).